# How to remove duplicate output in C program?

Tags: c, input, getchar

I've created a program that takes in a character from user input. It will convert the letter into uppercase and display it to the end user.

However, I am receiving an issue with the output where I get double of "Please enter a character in lower case:" and an extra line below. I'm not quite sure what is causing it but here is the program I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Converts lowercase letter to uppercase

int main()
{
    bool continue_program = true;

    printf("Program Running \n");
    int lower, upper;
    while (continue_program){
        printf("Please enter a character in lower case:");
        printf("\n");
        int lower = getchar();
        if(lower=='q' || lower=='Q'){
            printf("Goodbye \n");
            break;
        } else {
            upper = toupper(lower);
            putchar(upper);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output Example:

```
./a.out
Program Running 
Please enter a character in lower case:
a
A
Please enter a character in lower case:


Please enter a character in lower case:
b
B
Please enter a character in lower case:


Please enter a character in lower case:
p
P
Please enter a character in lower case:


Please enter a character in lower case:
Q
Goodbye
```

Comment: the posted code has the variable 'lower' defined twice, once near the top of the program and again inside the while loop.  Suggest only reference the variable while inside the 'while' loop rather than defining it again.

Comment: the code needs to consume the newline char that the user enters the requested char with.  Otherwise, a newline is input by the second call to getchar() and processed

Comment: Unrelated, but why have a continue_program variable and then use break to exit the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this:

```
int lower, upper;
```

to:

```
char lower, upper;
```

and this:

```
int lower = getchar();
```

to:

```
scanf(" %c", &lower);
     //^ Space which 'eats' remaning '\n' in the buffer
```

Comment: getchar() returns an int, so that part of the code is correct.  and this seems to miss the fact that the variable 'lower' is defined twice.